# Extract data in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, extract

I have table in Oracle 11g called Name: Customer

```
ID|Name |Country
1 |Mark |USA
2 |Allan|UK
3 |James|USA
4 |Todd |UK
5 |Mike |UK
```

And I have a text file list.txt

```
ID
1
3
5
```

I need Result exported in text file

result.txt

```
1 |Mark |USA
3 |James|USA
5 |Mike |UK
```

Basically I need to extract in the Customer table Record ID 1,3,5 and save it to a text file(result.txt) is this can be done in stored procedure or script.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Do you know how to load data from the text file into Oracle (SQL*Loader or external tables depending on where the file is located)?  Do you know how to write the query to join the two tables?  Do you know how to use `UTL_FILE` to generate the output file?

Comment: I don't know how to use UTL_FILE so far I tried only the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a table list(ID NUMBER) to store the content of list.txt
2. Use command sqlldr to import list.txt into table list

   `sqlldr  db_user/db_password@DB_SERVICE control=D:\list.ctl`

   the list.ctl content:

   `load`

   `infile 'D://list.txt'`

   `truncate into table test`

   `fields   terminated   by   '|'`

   `(id)`

3.Export the query result from oracle table:
   `sqlplus -S db_user/db_password@DB_SERVICE @D:\run.sql`

the run.sql content:

```
`SET echo OFF`

`SET feedback OFF`

`SET pagesize 0`

`SET term OFF`

`SET trims ON`

`SET timing OFF`

`SET verify OFF`

`SPOOL D:\result.txt`

`select a.id || '|' || a.name || '|' || a.Country From Customer a, list b`

`where a.id = b.id;`

`SPOOL OFF`

`quit`
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using external table to get data from file and join it with your table and export the data using utl_file in a stored procedure.

But if you are using shell or any other scripting languages then call a query directly from script and push the data to a file. Thats the easy way.